# Calculating the expected value of a discrete random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let the experiment is thrown a die two times then what is the expectation of occurring 5 or 6?
My try is if I do it with binomial distribution then we know that $E[X]=np$, where $n$ is the number of trials and $p$, is the probability of success, so here $n=2$ and $p=\frac{1}{3}$
so my $E[X]=\frac{2}{3}$
Now I want to calculate it with the help of the formula we have for expectation which is $E[X]=\sum_{x}xP(X=x)$ we have $X$=number of occur 5 or 6, so my $x$=0,1,2 and if I calculate $P(X=0)=\frac{16}{36}$ and $P(X=1)=\frac{18}{36}$ and $P(X=2)=\frac{2}{36}$ but I am confused how to apply the above formula for this one to get the same answer because with this I am not getting the same answer , where is the mistake I am doing here?.

Comment: You might want to check your calculations for $P(X = 1)$ and $P(X = 2)$. How do you obtain them?

Comment: $P(X=1)$ I am taking it is getting either 5 or 6 for example (1,5),(2,5), etc. and $P(X=2)$, I am taking it as getting two 5's or two 6's so (5,5) and (6,6) is it wrong? please explain.

Comment: For $X = 2$, you would be counting $(5, 5)$, $(5, 6)$, $(6,5)$, and $(6, 6)$. This matches your Binomial definition. If it were two 5s or two 6s exclusively, they would be different like you observed.

Comment: You can calculate the expected value of a random variable (like the value on a dice roll) but I don't know what you mean by the 'expectation of occurring 5 or 6'. Do you mean the probability of getting a 5 or 6 in two rolls?

Comment: I am defining my random variable $X$=getting 5 or 6 in two rolls.

Comment: Do you mean X = number of 5's or 6's in 2 rolls, so that X can take values 0, 1 or 2? Seems that is what you are doing, reading the question again.

Comment: @JKL but I assume (5,5),(5,6),(6,5) and (6,6) then $P(X=2)$=$\frac{4}{36}$ and if I apply the formula then we will have $E[X]$=$0.P(X=0)+1.P(X=1)+2.P(X=2)$=$\frac{18}{36}+2.\frac{4}{36}$=$\frac{11}{18}$ which is not same as binomial formula

Comment: @Paul $X$=number of 5's or 6's in two rolls means $X=0,1,2$ I am taking like in two rolls either we will get one 5 or 6 or maybe no 5,6 or maybe both 5,6?What am I missing here?

Comment: Why do you think X is a binomial random variable?

Comment: Because here we will have two outcomes success will be getting 5 or 6 and failure will be getting no 5 or 6

Comment: $P(X=1)$ is $\binom 21\times \frac 13\times \frac 23=\frac 49$, which is not what you wrote.  Similarly $P(X=2)=\frac 19$.

Comment: @Andyale check your calculation for $P(X = 1)$ too, as I mentioned

Comment: @lulu for $P(X=1) you have used the pdf of binomial distribution but I want to calculate it using only the sample space ,can you explain how to do that?

Comment: What's the problem?  The cases for which $X=1$ are $(5,Z), (6,Z), (Z,5), (Z,6)$ where $Z\in \{1,2,3,4\}$.  Thus there are $16$ such pairs.  As there are $36$ possible pairs (all equally probable) we get $\frac {16}{36}=\frac 49$ as before.

Comment: @lulu understand my mistake. Thank you.